# How to check if two key value pairs exists in list of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to check if a combination of two key-value pairs exists in list of dictionaries. Here is my list.

```
  data = 
  [
  {'transaction':'abc123', 'stage_one':'Started', 'stage_two':'Complete',   'version': 12),
  {'transaction':'abc123', 'stage_one':'Started', 'stage_two':'started',    'version': 12),
  {'transaction':'abc123', 'stage_one':'Started', 'stage_two':'processing', 'version': 12),
  {'transaction':'abc123', 'stage_one':'Started', 'stage_two':'Complete',   'version': 12)
  ]
```

I have tried the below line of code, but I always get **values exists** when invalid combinations of data is checked. Can someone please shed some light on this issue?

```
    if not any((d['stage_one'] ==('Started') and d['stage_two'] == 
    ('Complete123')) for d in data):
       print("values exists")
    else:
       print("values don't exists")
```

Comment: I think you want `if any`, instead of `if not any`

Comment: tried if any and was getting the same result. Below solution worked

Comment: You couldn't have gotten the same result.  `if any` and `if not any` are guaranteed to be opposite of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension on your list of dictionaries, with a conditional statement:

```
results = [d for d in data if d['stage_one'] =='some_value' and d['stage_two'] == 'some_other_value']
if len(results) > 0:
    print("values exists")
else:
    print("values don't exists")
```

This way, you can also check how many matches you have by looking at the length of `results`